# Why `Just String` will be wrong in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Hi I have a trivial but exhausting question during learning myself the **Parameterized Types** topic in Haskell. Here is my question:

Look this is the definition of `Maybe`:

```
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
```

And we use this like:

```
Just "hello world"
Just 100
```

But why can't Just take a **type variable**?

For example:

```
Just String
Just Int
```

I know this problem is quite fool, but I still can't figure it out...

Comment: What are you trying to do? What does `Just String` mean?

Comment: @DonStewart I guess it could mean "a type of all `Maybe String` values except `Nothing`".

Comment: Isn't "a type of all `Maybe String` values except `Nothing`" the same as `String`?

Comment: Don't you want to use `Maybe String` / `Maybe Int` instead?

Comment: @AaditMShah Yes they are isomorphic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, first note that `String` and `Int` aren't type variables, but types (type constants, if you will). But that doesn't really matter for the purpose of your question.

What matters is the destinction between Haskells *type language* and *value language*. These are generally kept apart. `String` and `Int` and `Maybe` live in the type language, while `"hello world"` and `100` and `Just` and `Nothing` live in the value language. Each knows nothing about the other side. Only, the compiler knows "this *discription* of a value belongs to that type", but really types exist only at compile-time and values exist only at runtime.

Two things that are a bit confusing:

- It's allowed to have names that exist both in the type- and value language. Best-known are `()` and mere synonym-type like

  ```
  newtype Endo a = Endo { runEndo :: a -> a }
  ```

  but really these are two seperate entities: the type constructor `Endo :: *->*` (see below for these `*` thingies) and the value constructor `Endo :: (a->a) -> Endo a`. They just happen to share the same name, but in completely different scopes – much like when you declare both `addTwo x = x + 2` and `greet x = "Hello "++x`, where both uses of the `x` symbol have nothing to do with each other.
- The `data` syntax seems to intermingle types and values. Everywhere else, types and values must always be separated by a `::`, most typically in signatures

  ```
       "hello world" :: String
       100           :: Int
       Just          :: Int -> Maybe Int
          {-hence-}Just 100 :: Maybe Int
       Nothing       :: Maybe Int

  foo :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> Maybe a  -- this really means `forall a . (Num a, Ord a) => a -> Maybe a
  foo n | n <= 0     = Nothing
        | otherwise  = Just $ n - 1
  ```

  and indeed that syntax can be used to define `data` in more distinctive way too, if you enable `-XGADTs`:

  ```
  data Maybe a where
    Just    :: a -> Maybe a
    Nothing :: Maybe a
  ```

  Now we have the `::` again as a clear distinction between value-level (left) and type-level.

---

You can actually take it up one more level: the above declaration can also be written

```
data Maybe :: * -> * where
  Just    :: a -> Maybe a
  Nothing :: Maybe a
```

Here `Maybe :: * -> *` means, "`Maybe` is a type-level thing that has *kind* `* -> *`", i.e. it takes a type-level argument of kind `*` (such as `Int`) and returns another type-level thing of kind `*` (here, `Maybe Int`). Kinds are to types as types are to values.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your explanation of "value-level" and "type-level" is fascinating! You know, what I've misunderstood is, type could act as a value. And according to your explanation, that's definitely wrong. However, could you pls give me a reference about the categorization? Thanks!

Comment: Well, any good Haskell book will do. [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters), [RWH](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/), or perhaps most upfront [YAHT](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~hal/docs/daume02yaht.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly declare `data Maybe a = Just String | Nothing`, and you can declare `data Maybe a = Just Int | Nothing`, but only one of them at a time. Using a type variable permits to declare in what way the type of the contents of the constructed values change with the value of the type variable. So `data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing` tells us that the contents "inside" `Just` is exactly of the type passed to `Maybe`. That way `Maybe String` means that "inside" `Just` there is a value of type `String`, and `Maybe Int` means that "inside" `Just` there is a value of type `Int`.

Comment: Thanks! I think the "replacement" approach is quite easy to understand!